# http:// a href link not working in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm using a webview in my Android App.

I have 3 buttons 1 for a link to a website one to call a number and one email button.

At first calling my website button worked, http://www.somelink.com  .

But my tel: link was not working. So I integrated some code that made my tel: button work.

The problem is that it has made my website or http: button not work?

The html button just does nothing when you click it.

```
package de.sonae.novolam;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class DFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dfragment, container, false);
WebView webView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                    Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent); 
    }

    return true;
}
    });
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/contact.html");
return mainView;
}

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
         startActivity( intent ); 
    }

    else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) { 

    }

    // Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity( intent ); 
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the web view when you handled url loading by your self and when you want do delegate handling on it. Simply return true from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` when you handled url loading by your own action. Return false otherwise:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                    Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent); 

            return true; // we handled the url loading
        }

        return false; // let WebView handle this event
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You have two `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` methods in your code. The only first one is actually called by a `WebView`. Move code from second `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to the first and it will work.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent); 
            return true;
        } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) { 
            // TODO : handle mail url
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The method shouldOverrideUrlLoading should return true if you want to override (i.e., prevent default handling) or false if you want things to work as normal.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```